# Dynamically adding contents to existed div element

Tags: javascript, html

I have created div element for text field, i need to add contents dynamically to that div element. As a novel I'm a little bit confused, I have tried using id for the input tag, can I do it by using javascript?.

```
<div>
   <input type="text" name="fullname" id="name">
</div>
```

please see above code, please instruct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the value of an ***input*** element you have to set the ***value*** property of the element like the following way:

```js
document.getElementById('name').value = 'New value';
```

```html
<div>
   <input type="text" name="fullname" id="name">
</div>
```